# Is it okay to use both Absolute Date and Repeats in Scheduled Reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Asking because the issue we are seeing is that if Absolute date is set for the reminder, and 'repeat' is enabled, then we get an sql condition like this:  ("20181212123815" <= DATE_ADD(, INTERVAL 1 month) which causes problems.

Should this combination be allowed, and hence the code/query needs to be improved to cope with this, or should the combination not be allowed and hence the UI needs to prevent users setting this up

Comment: Reminders I've tried with this type of set up generally break with SQL syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

It seems reasonable to allow that, although since the repetition "Until" is always relative, I can see why coding might have assumed the start would be relative.

If you plan to enhance that chunk of code, it might make sense to also allow an absolute end date or number of repetitions as alternatives to the relative "until".